# Como fazer um macro que clica em vários lugares?

Tags: javascript, c#, python, c

ola, gostaria de saber como fazer um .exe que atue como um macro, sempre que eu apertar a tecla ALT ele vai executar os clicks do mouse em determinada posição com o shift pressionado ao mesmo tempo.
Pode ser em qualquer linguagem, queria que o programa ficasse rodando de fundo mas no python sempre fecha.

máximo que consegui em python foi:

```
import pyautogui

pyautogui.keyDown('shift')
pyautogui.click(x=873, y=480, clicks=1, interval=0.01, button='left')
pyautogui.click(x=950, y=480, clicks=1, interval=0.01, button='left')
pyautogui.click(x=1030, y=480, clicks=1, interval=0.01, button='left')
pyautogui.keyUp('shift')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bom, sobre fazer ele ***executar uma sequência de comandos quando você pressionar uma tecla específica*** ou ***CTRL + Alguma coisa*** por exemplo você pode fazer os seguintes passos:

- Primeiro vou importar: `from pynput import keyboard` para mexer com ***hotkeys*** e permitir que você execute os comandos apenas apertando uma ***tecla*** ou ***uma combinação de teclas***.

> Documentação do ***pynput***: https://pynput.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

```
import pyautogui
from pynput import keyboard
```

> Lembre-se de dar o `pip install pynput`

- Depois vou transformar o código que você passou em uma função

> Isso facilita muito o ***processo de repetição*** dele dentro do script sem gastar muitas linhas

```
def clicar_personalizado():

    pyautogui.keyDown('shift')
    pyautogui.click(x=873, y=480, clicks=1, interval=0.01, button='left')
    pyautogui.click(x=950, y=480, clicks=1, interval=0.01, button='left')
    pyautogui.click(x=1030, y=480, clicks=1, interval=0.01, button='left')
    pyautogui.keyUp('shift')
```

- Agora vou adicionar permitir que ele rode funções a partir do que você pressionar no teclado usando o método ***keyboard.GlobalHotKeys*** do ***pynput*** da seguinte forma:

> Novamente segue o link dessa parte em específico:

```
with keyboard.GlobalHotKeys({
    '<alt>': clicar_personalizado, # "sequência de teclas": função
    '<ctrl>+f': quit, # Opcional apenas para fechar o script
}) as h:
    h.join()
```

> A documentação do pynput ensina outro modo de fazer isso por meio de  um ***listener***, mas pro seu caso acho que ***GlobalHotKeys*** é a melhor forma
> de fazer isso.

- No lugar do ***alt*** você pode colocar qualquer outra coisa como por exemplo: ***"ctrl+alt+q"***.

> As teclas ***ctrl e alt*** precisam estar dentro de ***< >***.

Código completo:

```
import pyautogui
from pynput import keyboard

def clicar_personalizado():
    pyautogui.keyDown('shift')
    pyautogui.click(x=873, y=480, clicks=1, interval=0.01, button='left')
    pyautogui.click(x=950, y=480, clicks=1, interval=0.01, button='left')
    pyautogui.click(x=1030, y=480, clicks=1, interval=0.01, button='left')
    pyautogui.keyUp('shift')

with keyboard.GlobalHotKeys({
    '<alt>': clicar_personalizado, # "sequência de teclas": função
    '<ctrl>+f': quit, # Opcional apenas para fechar o script
}) as h:
    h.join()
```

Agora sobre como tornar o programa em um ***.exe*** conheço duas formas:

- Utilizando pyinstaller:

> Recomendo esse vídeo aqui explicando como utilizar: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RMkPGjGhzxg

> Ou você pode seguir para documentação: https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/usage.html

- Utilizando ***Auto Py To Exe***:

> veja esse link aqui para o tutorial de como usar ele: https://dev.to/eshleron/how-to-convert-py-to-exe-step-by-step-guide-3cfi

Espero ter ajudado!

Comment: fala lucas tudo bom? eu consegui diminuir o tempo em ms de cada click, mas o tempo de resposta do alt esta bem baixo apos um segundo comando, por exemplo, tem como deixar o macro sempre que o alt tiver pressionado o codigo vai ficar em loop até eu soltar o alt ?

Comment: e sobre o executável , o .exe abre e fecha mesmo botando input no final do código

Comment: Eai blz? Mano sobre a questão ai do delay entre os cliques eu tenho esse problema recorrentemente com pyautogui tb, as vezes ele demora um pouco para executar os comandos. Sobre a questão de loop você pode pesquisar sobre listener e thread ou até mesmo o KeyCode() do `pynput` permitem que o código fique em loop até que você aperte uma tecla de cancelamento ou aperte ela dnv.

Comment: Sobre isso olha esse link aqui: https://nitratine.net/blog/post/python-auto-clicker/. O cara aqui está falando sobre click por exemplo mas você pode adicionar qualquer sequência de comandos diferentes nesse tutorial que ele está fazendo aí (é o modo de deixar em loop enquanto você manter apertado ou só apertar ele uma vez dnv)